# Passing a callback argument to cvCreateTrackbar

Tags: function, opencv, callback

I have a problem with the *callback* argument of the function cvCreateTrackbar. Here's the error I'm getting :

```
C:\Users\XELTINFO\ProjetVision\moyenetmedian.cpp:28: erreur : argument of type 'void (MoyenEtMedian::)(int)' does not match 'CvTrackbarCallback {aka void (*)(int)}'
```

And here's the code of the class :

```
int g_switch_value = 0;
int filterInt = 0;
int lastfilterInt = -1;

void MoyenEtMedian::switch_callback(int position)
{
    filterInt = position;
}

void MoyenEtMedian::exec(void)
{
    const char* name = "Filtres";
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "image.png" );
    IplImage* out = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
    cvNamedWindow( name, 1 );
    cvShowImage(name, out);

    // Create trackbar
    cvCreateTrackbar( "Filtre", name, &g_switch_value, 1,switch_callback );

    while( 1 ) {
        switch( filterInt ){
            case 0:
                cvSmooth( img, out, CV_BLUR, 7, 7 );
                break;
            case 1:
                cvSmooth( img, out, CV_MEDIAN, 7, 7 );
                break;
                    }
        if(filterInt != lastfilterInt){
            cvShowImage(name, out);
            lastfilterInt = filterInt;
        }
        if( cvWaitKey( 15 ) == 27 )
            break;
    }

    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvReleaseImage( &out );
    cvDestroyWindow( name );
}
```

I intend to connect the exec function to a button via a Slot.

Answer (score 2):

The callback function you defined (`void MoyenEtMedian::switch_callback(int position)`) is a member function of `MoyenEtMedian`. As such it gets an implicit member of type `MoyenEtMedian*` added by the compiler and is not of type `void (*)(int)`. You are therefore getting this error message.

To solve the problem you can define the member function `switch_callback` as `static`, but then you won't be able to use the class members in your function. You can also define a callback function which is not a class member function.

Comment: Okay. Now I have another problem, I want to connect "MoyenEtMedian::exec" to a button like this : "QObject::connect(ui->bMoyMed,SIGNAL(clicked()),m1,SLOT(m1::exec));" but it isn't working. The class not declared in scope.

Comment: Which error are you getting, can you post more code ? Can you please accept my answer and upvote it if it solved your initial problem ?